# Doctrine EntityManager is Closed - How to continue save an objects

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a collection of entities (with relations) of and iterate over there. On the 5th iteration, SQL exception has been thrown, after it, EntityManager is closed. 
I can re-create an EntityManager, but I lose relations on my next entity (new Entity manager will detect relations as new entities and will try to save cascade)

Is there any way to save entities in the loop and continue to do it after DBAL Exception?

Comment: you can try to refresh all entities. but I would rather advise to prevent exceptions from happening at all, if possible (and it probably is)

Comment: Diar @Jakumi, I will be happy if you're suggest me a way to privent encoding-related exceptions. I try to handle last layer-erorrs to privent crash my service. BTW, how to refresh all entities ? (re-fetch it?)

Comment: I think, it would be better to solve your actual problem (not inserting invalid data) then fixing a different problem (entity manager dies)

Comment: if you really want to not solve the actual problem (invalid data inserted into db), you might take a look at a) merge https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_merge or b) getReference https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_getReference . all inserted entities have a reference, and if they are detached can be reattached to the new entitymanager or you could use a reference instead (which uses less memory and less queries I believe).